# Play games with one's reputation / dignity

Tags: sentence-meaning

Suppose someone is trying to endanger your reputation / dignity. For example you borrowed some money from somebody and did not clear the check you drew for him for the borrowed money; he comes to your office and starts shut and make a situation in which you lose face in front of your staff. Then the following sentence which is a translation from my mother language would work in English or it sounds like something unidiomatic to you:

> - Don’t play games with my dignity.

Comment: I don't think "dignity" is quite an apposite word in this situation; synonymous with "self-respect", it's not the trait anyone but yourself can do  any harm to. Maybe it is something synonymous with "trustworthiness/trustiness" that you are looking for.

Comment: @Rompey, dignity is about other people's respect for you, not your self-respect. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dignity

Comment: @A-friend: "[you] did not pass the check you drew for him for the borrowed money"... what does this mean- you did not give him the check?

Comment: @JavaLatte - Thank you very much. I thought it is how a man evaluates himself that he gets a dignity about himself from, acts  and dies with it, and nothing, even the near end, can deprive him of his dignity if he really has it.  And it's because of this dignity, as a manifestation of his self-respect, that people respect him.

Comment: @Rompey, You are right, a person's dignity is about their **behaviour** and how others perceive it, and nobody else can deprive a person of that, but it is most certainly not about how a man **evaluates himself** (that's self-respect), it's how he **behaves**.

Comment: @A-friend: - Like JavaLatte, try as I might, I can't understand what you mean by _did not pass the check you drew for him for the borrowed money_.

Comment: @JavaLatte I think it means the check to pay back the loan bounced.

Comment: Thank you very much @JavaLatte and P.E. Dant for letting me know about my typo. I meant "clearing the check" in our question.

Comment: @A-friend: A person with dignity wold not give somebody a cheque that bounces. So this person doesn't have any dignity for anybody else to play with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression "*Don't play games with...*" is quite common.  To play games with something is to treat it without respect - to treat it lightly.

In your example, you are right "*Don't play games with my dignity*" would work as an expression.

However, a more common expression in English would be "*Don't play games with me*".  That is often heard and covers all aspects of your dignity and reputation.  It also implies that the person to whom you are speaking is trying to deceive you.